# SQL Server indexes for Order By operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a table with 30k rows and more than 80 columns.
Selecting 100 items from this table, ordered by a column is quite a slow operation. Adding an index for that particular column only, it improves the query a lot.

I have these queries sorted by the user input and there are 9 options from where he can choose.

The question is: would it be optimal to create 9 indexes for all these columns or should I take another approach? I know that creating a single index with all these columns will not improve anything.

Comment: Yes, creating nine separate indices will speed up all your queries - but at a cost: other operations like `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will be slower (since each operation must also update all those indices, now). So the question is: **how important** is the query speed? And how **likely** are all those nine sort options being used? If you can limit yourself to maybe the 2, 3 more frequent sort options, that might be a good compromise between making the most frequent queries fast, and *not* put too much burden on updates/inserts

Comment: Please paste your query execution plan

Comment: Query speeds are really important for the application. The data comes from an import webjob, so I would say the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` are not that important.[Execution Plan](https://imgur.com/a/ZXJWF6f)

Comment: The indexes may or may not work.  How are the 100 items being chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is of the form:

```
select top (100) t.*
from t
order by col;
```

Then an index on `col` is going to help.  SQL Server will find the 100 rows using the index, then bring back the rest of the columns.

If you have 9 such columns, then a separate index for each one will speed up the query.

If you can start combining the columns, the indexes are only going to help for single column choices.  So consider these five clauses:

```
order by col1
order by col1, col2
order by col1, col2, col3
order by col1, col3
order by col1, col3, col2
```

To fully cover these `order by`s, you need two indexes -- `(col1, col2, col3)` and `(col1, col3, col2)`.  The leading columns in the index have to fully match the columns in the `order by` -- in the same order and no gaps.

Also note that each index does add a bit of overhead to insert, update, and delete operations.  However, it sounds like querying the data is the bigger issue, so you may not have to worry about that overhead.